# Amazon AWS Service Error

Tags: amazon-web-services, drupal, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I am currently trying to set up a Virtual Machine and a Database Server for my website to launch off of. I decided to go with Amazon's AWS.

I have beeing working through [This Tutorial](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/gettingstarted/latest/wah-linux/getting-started-deploy-app.html) and am at Part 3 now.

I got to the point where I started the Apache Web Server and went to my local DNS name in my browser, and successfully saw the Test Page.

I proceeded forward with Downloading "Drupal" and got to the section where it says "Configure Drupal". I am now trying to load my local DNS name in my browser again, only to get a 500 Server Error.

I'm not sure what could've went wrong, I only entered the commands in the tutorial for the whole section on "Install Drupal".

Thank you

EDIT: Also, what exactly does Drupal do? And do I need to use it?

Comment: Did you end up resolving this issue? I am currently having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Drupal is a CMS system, and you don't have to use it. It is only being used to provide an example for a website. Instead of installing Drupal, you can install your own site on the server if you prefer or even something like Wordpress if you're more familiar with that.

However, if you do want to follow the example your best bet for discovering the problem is to look into what the exact error is. You should be able to find more information about that in the log files located in `/var/log/httpd`. The error log in there should show you more details about what failed.